# Kubernetes behind explicit proxy

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to run a Kubernetes 1.6 cluster with Hyperkube behind an explicit proxy.
All traffic from the master / nodes end up on {proxy-ip}:8080.

As the cluster needs to make outgoing HTTP calls to the underlying cloud provider, it fails and the Hyperkube container are exited, all but kubelet which tries to query the kubeapi locally and fails (since it's not running).

I know I need to set up the http_proxy/https_proxy/no_proxy settings, so far I've configured them at /etc/environment, and for docker.service.d (using http-proxy.conf / https-proxy.conf) and kubelet.service.

Do I need to pass in the proxy settings to the hyperkube files as well?
What am I missing?

Thanks